# Monotouch open pdf on device?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to open a pdf from my bundle in monotouch app. I don't know if it is from the path or not but i can't open that pdf. Can somebody give me an example of how to open a pdf file? I am using pdftron library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure your file is marked as `Content` in the `Build Action` from MonoDevelop. That will ensure it gets copied inside your application bundle.

Then, from your application, you can get your application bundle path using the following property:

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath
```

From this you can try to probe for your file, e.g.

```
if (File.Exists (Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "myfile.pdf")) {
    Console.WriteLine ("got it");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("can't find it");
}
```

Once you find the *right* path to your file you should be able to provide it to your PDF library.

Comment: Do you have the name of the frameworks for pdfTron i think it might be a problem also there?

Comment: @PirlituVasilica no, it's the first time I heard of this library

Comment: @PirlituVasilica if you're asking which iOS frameworks it needs, it needs QuartzCore, UIKit, CoreGraphics, Foundation and CoreText.

Answer (score 1):

PDFtron doesn't have .net bindings as far as I know.

iOS has integrated PDF reading capabilities, and Xamarin itself provides a sample for you to consume. I recently coded a PDF reader using that sample.

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ZoomingPdfViewer

Comment: PDFTron does have .NET bindings, as well as a native iOS library with an Obj-C interface.

Comment: But the iOS library is Obj-C you'd need to write your own .NET bindings to use it with monotouch